# Puppeteer how to store results in an object variable?

Tags: javascript, object, puppeteer

How do I store data in an object variable. I thought I was familiar with object variables but I guess not. I am trying to store my data like this.

```
Product:{
   Title: Bla Bla Bla
}
Product:{
   Title: Ala Ala Ala
}
```

Here is the code I currently have.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    let movieURL = 'https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=&cat_id=91083';

    let productName = []
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(movieURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

     let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        productName = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.product-title-link')].map(a => a.innerText)

        return{
            productName
        }
    })

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close()
})();
```

The results I get are like this.

```
{
  productName: [
    'SQ Non Chlorinated Brake Parts Cleaner',
    'Super Tech DEF Diesel Exhaust Fluid, 2.5 Gallon',
    'Mobil 1 Advanced Fuel Economy Full Synthetic Motor O ...\n',
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance if you any of you guys or girls can help. :)
Here are some things I have already tried.

```
productName += [...document.querySelectorAll('a.product-title-link')].map(a => a.innerText)
productName[data] = {[...document.querySelectorAll('a.product-title-link')].map(a => a.innerText)}
productName = {[...document.querySelectorAll('a.product-title-link')].map(a => a.innerText)}
```

All of those above give errors and do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in your `map()` do something like:

`(a) => ({ Product: { Title: a.innerText } })`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  let movieURL = "https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=&cat_id=91083";

  let productName = [];
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  let page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(movieURL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

  let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    productName = [
      ...document.querySelectorAll("a.product-title-link"),
    ].map((a) => ({ Product: { Title: a.innerText } }));

    return {
      productName,
    };
  });

  console.log(data);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Okay getting closer when I run that I get { Product: [Object] } for all of them.

Comment: Hmm isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: Oh no sorry if i wasnt being specific enough. I am looking for the products in place of the { Product: [**Object**] }

Comment: The `[Object]` holds `{ Title: 'Super Tech Engine Starting Fluid, 11 fl oz' }`

Comment: How do I make it console.log it?

Comment: Try, `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`